# Как скруглить края фона для меню?

Tags: меню, border

Для меню в качестве фона используется изображение. Края рамки меню скругляются через border-radius, но при этом за скругленными краями вылезает квадратное фоновое изображение. Его только фотошопом резать? или можно как-то с помощью стилей привести в нужный вид? Код не мой, я его только редактирую по мере разумения и умения. Буду признательна за подсказку и совет.

```
#menu1{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    z-index:10;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
    #menu1 ul{
        position:relative; 
        display:block;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
        list-style:none;
        background-image: url(/images/fonmenu.jpg);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Методом тыка определила, что если background-image перенести в menu1, поближе к border-radius, то волшебным образом все скругляется вместе. Спасибо за вдохновение))

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/219779)

Comment: @Viktorov, это ответ. Один из вариантов решения.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что у блока по умолчанию `overflow: visible`, при котором все вылазиющик куски всё равно видно. Поэтому либо фон должен принадлежать самому блоку, либо надо ставить `overflow: hidden`:

```css
section { 
  border: 1em solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 8em;
  width: 8em;
  
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,255,.25);
}

.bg {
  background: rgba(0,0,255,.25);
}

.bg div {
  background: none;
}

.oh {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<section><div></div></section>
<section class=bg><div></div></section>
<section class=oh><div></div></section>
```